# Phonegap Video plugin?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-video-player

When creating video plugin from the following link [Phonegap Video plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer) everything is working good & executing fine. But here that particular video is saving into our internal storage & playing. But what i want is need to play that video directly without saving into internal or external storage. I tried, but getting error in simulator as **Sorry,this video cannot be played**. I don't know where i am doing mistake. Can anyone please help me with this.

Waiting for your reply & Thanks in advance....

code:

```
//in button onclick="show()" method i am passing the particular url....

     function show()
    {

  window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/BigBuckBunny.mp4");
    }
```

Comment: What URL do you pass to the VideoPlayer?

Comment: window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/BigBuckBunny.mp4"); this is the url i'm passing

Comment: Actually Simon, first i gone through your blog also. By that i came to know that video is saving internally. So, can you help me with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so the VideoPlayer can play videos from 3 different types:

1) SD Card

```
file:///sdcard/BigBuckBunny.mp4
```

which will play directly from the SD Card. The SD Card on Android is fully open with privileges so any application will be able to access the file.

2) Assets

```
file:///android_asset/www/BigBuckBunny.mp4
```

The only app that can get access to the assets is your own. So in order for the VideoPlayer app, which we start via an Intent, to get access to the video is to copy it to a temporary location on the sd card.

3) HTTP

```
http://www.bigbuckbunny.com/BigBuckBunny.mp4
```

The Video Player will just stream this video.

Comment: When I play it over http for larger videos (say 100MB), it waits a while and then eventually gives me a "Sorry, this video cannot be played". Any idea what's going on here, and how I can get it working?